# Issues with html5 video driven site

Tags: html, video

I have a website where upon loading, a 9 MB video autoplays.  I also have it so that whenever a user clicks off the homepage using the navigation bar, a 2MB video plays before it ultimately goes to it's target destination.  The issue is that while the 9MB video loads seamlessly, the 2 MB ones lag behind and the full video doesn't play before it goes to the other page.  I even have it so that there is a delay before it switches to the other page via jQuery, so the video can finish.

Is the lag caused by the fact that the videos need to load fully and my ISP isn't fast enough, or is there a way to actually speed them up?  I am fairly certain that the answer is the former, but I am just wanting to make sure.

http://www.brokenrecordsaustin.com/test/
Click on "Us" to see what I mean.

Comment: What kind of line are you using?  I just checked it on two more computers here that are on the same network I was working on it with, and they didn't load as they should have.

Comment: It was on my works internet, from home it does lag. But you perhaps want to try the preload attribute? http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_video_preload.asp

Comment: I tried it, but the thing is, I don't think any of the videos can be pre-loaded, as I have them replace the picture of the door when any of the navbar links are clicked with jQuery.  Since those elements only come into being when clicked, the preload attribute is nullified.

Comment: Can't you load the video behind the image? And then hide the image div and start the animation with javascript?